# Integrating Sceneform SDK Using Android Studio

Tags: sceneform

I downloaded Android Studio 3.1 but I cannot find any reference or docs on how to create a new project which uses Sceneform SDK. I am not looking for Sample Apps, I am interested in knowing how to integrate Sceneform SDK using Android Empty Project.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's not too much documentation about starting from scratch. But the steps are the following:

1. Install the Sceneform Android Studio plugin using the Plugin section of the Android Studio settings
2. Add Sceneform gradle dependencies (just copy from a sample project)
3. Add an ArFragment or an ArSceneView to your app

The Sceneform plugin should extends your build.gradle file to include the tasks for convert your 3D models to SFB files. Otherwise check https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/sceneform/import-assets to add it manually.